# How to debug php that is launched when an ajax event occurs

Tags: php, ajax

I have an index.html file that consist of a button that triggers an ajax request and launches a php file.The php file sends data to the server.  The problem is I don't know how to debug the php file as echo doesn't seem to work ( I'm probably doing it wrong). I simply want to echo various variables to divs in the html file and see what they are at different points in the program. If there is a better way to do this please post. Thank you.

**PHP**

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
?>

<?php

// Create table

$patchData = $_POST[mydata];
$encoded = json_encode($patchData);
$sql="INSERT INTO patches (patch_name)
VALUES ('{$encoded}')";





// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Table updated successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error updating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
var patch = { 
"patch_name": "",
    "sound_type": {
        "synths": [     // each 'synth name' is a draggable div that plays an oscillator

        // etc

        ],
        "samplers": [ 
            // same as synth only for divs that trigger audio files instead of oscillators
        ]
    }, 

}
// START Save DOM nodes

function save(){
    instrumentName = $('#instrument-name-form').val();

    patch.sound_type.synths.length = 0;
    patch.sound_type.samplers.length = 0;

    $(".synth").each(function(){
        var temp = $( "#" + this.id ); 
        var pos = $(temp).position();
        console.log(this.id);
        patch.sound_type.synths.push({'synth_name':this.id,'xpos':pos.left,'ypos':pos.top});
        });

        $('.patch-list').html(patch.name);
        patch.patch_name = instrumentName ;

        console.log(patch);



            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/add.php',
            data: {mydata: patch},    
            success: function(){
                console.log('yay');
            }


            });



};



$('#save-synths').click(function(){
    save(); 


})
```

Comment: echo and then firebug, you will see the output in the net panel, or debug to file, error log, even email

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Code posted.

Comment: Chrome dev tools > network > xhr tab > response tab will show you php errors that were output from the php file.

Or go to your server error log for PHP errors (also turn on error reporting first)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways for doing it .
First , internet explorer javascript debugging mode.(Or firebug is even better)
Second , rename the index.html to the index.php , Then open 
 tags before ajax and breakpoint to echo page , then debug the php 
{
if you dont know how to debug php 
please enable the xdebug control in the php.ini file and
use zend studio or eclipse or netbeans for php ide , also php storm works for it .
}

Answer (score 0):

**first** : change this line `$patchData = $_POST[mydata];`  to `$patchData = $_POST['mydata'];`

**second** : the `patch` object structure is wrong  and could not be send to server so you have to edit it

Comment: Actually the data is being sent over the server and stored in a table. I intend to write a loop to extract the individual values and do it but as a test I just wanted to do it this way to get started. Also, ['mydata'] and [mydata] both work.

Answer (score 0):

[Debugging with firebug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4jXAaEMp2M)

or you may also use file based logging of php variables.